# Data Access Layer and DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn the idea of Domain Driven Design and trying to figure out where should we put the Database persistence code.

Going through the book "Implementing Domain Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon", I understand that the Repository or the Database operations (along with connections etc.,) have to be kept in the Model project (Domain Model Context) itself. Is my understanding correct?

I am referring to his sample of IdentityAccessContext, AgilePMContext etc., where there are interfaces to the repository. I had always grown with an idea of having a separate Data Layer and adding one here leads me to circular dependency. Because the Interfaces, Entities are declared in Model which is required for the Data layer and the Data layer needs to be referred from model for persistence.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Going through the book "Implementing Domain Driven Design by Vaughn
>   Vernon", I understand that the Repository or the Database operations
>   (along with connections etc.,) have to be kept in the Model project
>   (Domain Model Context) itself. Is my understanding correct?

Repository abstractions (interfaces) should be in the Domain layer, but their concrete implementations are in an Infrastructure layer.

See his code samples for the book : https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm, for instance `TeamRepository` interface in domain/model and `LevelDBTeamMemberRepository` in port/adapter/persistence.

There's no circular reference because persistence is strongly coupled to Domain but Domain is only loosely coupled to persistence if it ever needs it (thanks to Inversion of Control, most of the time achieved by Dependency Injection).

Comment: @guillame31, thank you. I was missing this link in the C# project version. So it was a bit confusing, and both yours as well as Matias answers are leading me to some understanding. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say there's a data access layer per se.

Actually, repositories translate domain into data and viceversa using a data mapper.

Models, services or transaction scripts must use repositories to both get and persist objects. There's no circular reference here:

- Service layer injects repository/repositories to implement domain operations. That is, a service will know what to do if it requires **objects** and it's not focused on how they're translated into data.
- Repositories use a data mapper to persist and get data <sup>(1)</sup>.
- Data mapper usually is an OR/M like Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper...

Furthermore, a good DDD will enforce *[inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)* and this will mean that:

- Upper layers know about lower layers.
- Lower layers don't own any reference to upper layers.

In summary, DDD doesn't have a DAL like you think, but it tries to abstract and encapsulate each concern in order to let upper layers be decoupled from the underlying data approach.

### About the circular reference thing...

OP said:

> Because the Interfaces, Entities are declared in Model which is
> required for the Data layer and the Data layer needs to be referred
> from model for persistence.

Double check your statement. If models represent higher layer of abstraction than data, *why* data should reference models?

It would be the model who requires the data. And the data should be accessed using interfaces to let the models be agnostic about the data access strategy. **This is called *[inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)*, as I said previously on this answer**.

Maybe you think that data layer requires a reference to entities, because you're still thinking the old way, but if you practice a good separation of concerns and you work with a data mapper (or you implement it yourself), the data mapper just maps objects to raw data and viceversa, and it doesn't require a reference to concrete classes like domain objects (*you should ask yourself how Entity Framework can persist your entities to your favourite database engine without even knowing about these entities <sup>(2)</sup>*).

Anyway, as I said before on this answer too, you shouldn't think about a DAL but a bunch of repositories and a data mapper, or just repositories (see *exception (1)*).

Usually dependent lower layers are instantiated and given to upper layers using [dependency injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (a possible implementation of [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)).

---

*<sup>(1) Exception to this rule: if we're no talking about a relational storage, maybe there's no data mapper at all, and repository implements its interface by accessing the data with lower level of abstraction/encapsulation. For example, if the repository implements its operations to store data in XML, then it would use an XDocument or XmlDocument internally and there's no actual data mapper at all.</sup>*

*<sup>(2) Actually OR/M frameworks like Entity Framework can know how's your model by configuration. While it doesn't require a reference to your concrete domain to compile, it requires you to provide class maps using Code First or other approaches)</sup>*

Comment: Thanks, So this adds a 2 or 3 more layers like One project for defining repository abstractions with all IRepository, second one for the actual repository implementations and a third one for DTO objects. I agree on your note on DI and IOC and upper layer's knowledge on lower layers, they all are clear.

Comment: @Muthu You're confusing layers with Visual Studio projects. Repository interfaces can live in the same project as implementations. You're right DTO should live in a separate project, because both domain and other layers may need DTOs.

Comment: Fidemraizer, ok, thank you. So we need a separate DTO layer object and flatten the data set before saving, hmm. This makes sense for an RDBMS. What will happen in the case of scenarios like using nosql document object store like Mongo?

Comment: @Muthu You shouldn't ask other questions as part of a single question. Instead, if you feel my answer has already answered the original question, you should mark it as the right one, and ask a new question. Once you've published it, if you want, you can share with me the link and I'll answer this new specific question in the new Q&A :)

Comment: @Muthu I see you marked the other answer, and it's absolutely wrong... A repository implementation isn't an infrastructure detail.

Comment: Most of the reference projects by Vernon seem assume they are implementation details @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: @UK-AL When I said *repository implementation* I was talking about an implementation to the most generic interface to cover most basic aspects of any repository. I don't know if this changes your point.

Comment: @UK-AL I see that instead of discussing the whole thing you've downvoted my answer...

Comment: Having a generic repository in DDD is generally considered to be bad, because the method names have to be really generic like Create, update, delete etc as opposed to using ubiquitous language. The repo interface should be specific to that aggregate. Sometimes I will do something similar by injecting a generic database access layer into the repo to help with implementation. But that makes it even more of a infrastructure issue. @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: Generally if its using a specific technology for persisting to a database, dapper, orm, database specific SQL. It's going to be infrastructure or an adapter.

Comment: @UK-AL I don't buy that approach. It's too dogmatic. Software should be DRY too. If let's say `AddOrUpdate`, `Remove`, `GetById` can be generalized, it reduces overall code complexity, and who requires something ubiquitous may be defined by a concrete repository interface...

Comment: You can make it dry by injecting a generic access layer into the specialised repo. Greg young has an example http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/ @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: Also this generic repository thing doesn't really matter on classifying repository implementations as infrastructure. Infrastructure and Adapters include basically everything outside of the core "business logic" in DDD. The repository interfaces are normally considered part of the domain, because they normally include things like .AllOpenOrders(), but how to actually retrieve that is database specific and not core business logic. Hence implementation of repos normally go in the infrastructure part of the project.

Comment: @UK-AL In real world scenarios where you interface a RDBMS using an OR/M or the whole library to work with NoSQL storage are mostly *data mappers*, there's nothing wrong with injecting the *data mapper* into a base repository class. Obviously, you'll end up with domain repository interfaces to cover specific domain requirements, but most basic ones will be inherited from the base repository implementation which is defined in the infrastructure layer... Probably you're pointing to [something like this](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/agnostic-repository)

Comment: @UK-AL BTW, since most projects won't need a data tech switch in 10, 15 years, I prefer to stay with an abstract repository which implements some basic rules, inherited by a tech-specific abstract repository implementing some basic operations, and I define domain repository interfaces that are implemented by derived classes of that abstract repository coupled to some tech. At the end of the day, I'll still be able to use other underlying data techs deriving other abstract repositories, or I'll be able to refactor any repository to inherit a new abstract repository as (...)

Comment: @UK-AL (...) implements the same infrastructre interface... BTW I hope I could explain it clearly...

Comment: I don't see anything here that refutes the fact repository implementations are infrastructure issues. A good DDD domain is basically pure POCO objects. Keeping repo implementations in your domain means your coupling your domain to a specific technology like entity framework.  The whole point of DDD is to build a core that purely focuses on modeling your business, without any technology factors involved. @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: @UK-AL I believe that there's a controversy about *domain are pure POCOs* since those domains are called *anemic*.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That's not what anemic domain is. Anemic is when your domain models don't have any behaviour or business logic within them. POCOs are allowed to have to behaviour and methods attached. What is not allowed is dependencies on different technologies, and Entity framework attributes etc

Comment: @UK-AL Sorry, I believe that the commenting system isn't the best approach to discuss this... You're not understanding my reasoning... But anyway, it's hard to get conclusions from comments. We would need a forum...